# Sorting JS array without reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="listing"></ul>
```

**JS:**

```
// sort functions:

function SortLen(arr, ascYN) {
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (ascYN) return a.length - b.length;
            else return b.length - a.length;
        });
    }

function SortAZ (arr) {
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a < b) return -1;
            else if (a > b) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

function SortZA (arr) {
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a > b) return -1;
            else if (a < b) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

// define array

var listing = document.getElementById("listing");
var myStringArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Volkswagon", "Ford"];

// sort the array

// SortLen( myStringArray, false );
// SortLen( myStringArray, true );
// SortAZ( myStringArray );
SortZA( myStringArray );

// display the array

var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    listing.innerHTML += "<li>" + myStringArray[i] + "</li>";
}
```

As the code stands at the moment, I have to comment out out of the sort options to change the sort output e.g.

```
SortLen( myStringArray, false );
// SortLen( myStringArray, true );
// SortAZ( myStringArray );
// SortZA( myStringArray );
```

And then I have to reload the page to pick up the change and sort the array differently.

I wondered if there could be any way I could change the code so that I can add links to the HTML to add links - e.g.

```
<div id="sort">
    <a href="#" onclick="SortLen( myStringArray, false );">Long - Short</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="SortLen( myStringArray, true );">Short-Long</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="SortAZ( myStringArray );">Short-Long</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="SortZA( myStringArray );">Long-Short</a>
</div>
```

So that when clicked, the LI items generated would be resorted dynamically without refreshing the page each time.

Comment: While I don't understand what you want, if that is copied from your actual code you may want to replace "onlcick" with "onclick".

Comment: If you don't need to change the URL, `<button type="button" onclick="...">...<button>` would be more semantically and functionally appropriate for triggering arbitrary JavaScript.

Comment: What error do you get in the console?

Comment: I don't get an error in the console - if I add `console.log(myStringArray);` to each sort function, and then click the sort link, the array is sorted correctly, but then the output of the page is not refreshed to reflect the re-sorted array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should extract the display in a separate method that you would call after every sort :

```
function draw (array) {
  var arrayLength = array.length;
  document.getElementById('listing').innerHTML = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    document.getElementById('listing').innerHTML += "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";
  }
}
```

You should avoid inline event handling, and attach an event handler to the dom elements:

```
<a id="a" href="#" >Long - Short</a>

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  SortLen( myStringArray, false );
  draw(myStringArray)
})
```

See [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kf600oh/1/)

Html

```
<div id="sort">
    <a id="a" href="#" >Long - Short</a>
    <a id="b" href="#" >Short-Long</a>
    <a id="c" href="#" >Short-Long</a>
    <a id="d" href="#" >Long-Short</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 const SortLen = function (arr, ascYN) {
     arr.sort(function (a, b) {
         if (ascYN) return a.length - b.length;
         else return b.length - a.length;
     });
  }

function SortAZ (arr) {
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a < b) return -1;
            else if (a > b) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

function SortZA (arr) {
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a > b) return -1;
            else if (a < b) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    }

// define array

var listing = document.getElementById("listing");
var myStringArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Volkswagon", "Ford"];

// sort the array
SortZA( myStringArray );

function draw (array) {
  var arrayLength = array.length;
  document.getElementById('listing').innerHTML = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    document.getElementById('listing').innerHTML += "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";
  }
  console.log(array)
}
draw(myStringArray)


document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
console.log('okok')
  SortLen( myStringArray, false );
  draw(myStringArray)
})
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  SortLen( myStringArray, true );
  draw(myStringArray)
})
document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  SortAZ( myStringArray );
  draw(myStringArray)
})
document.getElementById('d').addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  SortZA( myStringArray );
  draw(myStringArray)
})
```

Comment: That's a big help, thank you so much for taking the time to do that, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild html each time you sort the table. Your code change html only on load and after that only array is sorted. It is simple javascript not angular where it could work. You can try this code:

```
<div id = "sort" >
    < a href="javascript:SortLen( myStringArray, false ); rebuild();">Long - Short</a>
    <a href = "javascript:SortLen( myStringArray, true ); rebuild();" > Short - Long </ a >
    < a href="javascript:SortAZ( myStringArray ); rebuild();">Short-AZ</a>
    <a href = "javascript:SortZA( myStringArray ); rebuild();" > Long - ZA </ a >
</ div >

< ul id="listing"></ul>

<script>

function SortLen(arr, ascYN)
{
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (ascYN) return a.length - b.length;
        else return b.length - a.length;
    });
}

function SortAZ(arr)
{
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a < b) return -1;
        else if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}

function SortZA(arr)
{
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a > b) return -1;
        else if (a < b) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}

// define array

var myStringArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Volkswagon", "Ford"];

// sort the array

// SortLen( myStringArray, false );
// SortLen( myStringArray, true );
// SortAZ( myStringArray );
SortZA(myStringArray );
rebuild();
// display the array

function rebuild()
{
    var listing = document.getElementById("listing");
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    listing.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        listing.innerHTML += "<li>" + myStringArray[i] + "</li>";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. Out of interest - do you know how I could output the contents of the array when the page first loads? So that it still displays the arrays contents before a user has clicked any link, before the `rebuild` function is triggered? Then if a user clicks to sort data, `rebuild` is called...

Comment: I added rebuild(); function to the script after this line in code: SortZA(myStringArray );

Comment: Great - thanks for your help with this, it's much appreciated.