# Javascript sort method does not sort after initial run

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort table rows by a data-attribute. This attribute is an integer. I have a custom sort order that these integers need to be sorted by. The following code snippet works completely as intended....but only one time. If I try to run it again after changing the data-attribute of a random item, it does not run again. Moreover, when I first run it, I'm console logging "sorting" on each run. I have 16 initial rows, and it's outputting 46 logs on first run. Every run after that, it's only outputting 15 logs so I'm thinking that is why it's not properly sorting but I don't know how to fix it. I'm not deleting any rows or changing anything other than the html in the inspector to modify the data-attribute where it's pulling the sort order integer from.

```
    function sortItems() {
        //my custom order of how to sort the rows
        sortList = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 17, 9, 16, 10, 18, 11, 19, 13, 12, 14, 15]
        $tbody = $('#queueTable tbody');
        $tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
            console.log('sorting')
            tda = sortList.indexOf($(a).data('status'));
            tdb = sortList.indexOf($(b).data('status'));
            return tda > tdb ? 1
                :
                tda < tdb ? -1
                :
                0;
        }).appendTo($tbody);
    }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="queueTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Encounter #</th>
            <th scope="col">Location</th>
            <th scope="col">Doctor</th>
            <th scope="col">Current Tech</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Current Status / Total Time</th>
            <th scope="col">Status Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr wire:id="aTiQ4U0TDx21BYTuLrTg" data-status="3" data-selectable="itemRow" wire:ignore="" id="row60833" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffed4a , #ffed4a)" class="should-alert">
            <td scope="row"><a href="#" target="_blank">301581 </a></td>
            <td> <span wire:click="setCurrentLocation(374)" style="cursor: pointer" title="548">
                DS00118/MN
            </span>
                <br> </td>
            <td wire:click="buildDocReassignModal" style="cursor: pointer; "> Dr. White </td>
            <td id="usercell60833" class="userCell" data-id="">
                <div style="font-size: 24pt;" role="button" wire:click="resolveIssue(true)">
                    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-robot fa-w-20" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="robot" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
                        <path fill="currentColor" d="M32,224H64V416H32A31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1,0,384V256A31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1,32,224Zm512-48V448a64.06328,64.06328,0,0,1-64,64H160a64.06328,64.06328,0,0,1-64-64V176a79.974,79.974,0,0,1,80-80H288V32a32,32,0,0,1,64,0V96H464A79.974,79.974,0,0,1,544,176ZM264,256a40,40,0,1,0-40,40A39.997,39.997,0,0,0,264,256Zm-8,128H192v32h64Zm96,0H288v32h64ZM456,256a40,40,0,1,0-40,40A39.997,39.997,0,0,0,456,256Zm-8,128H384v32h64ZM640,256V384a31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1-32,32H576V224h32A31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1,640,256Z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select wire:model="status" class="block-refresh">
                    <option>Ready for Refraction</option>
                    <option value="1">Testing</option>
                    <option value="4">Ready for Ref (spanish)</option>
                    <option value="5">Ready for OR</option>
                    <option value="6">Ready for OR (Spanish)</option>
                    <option value="7">Ready for Ref (no doc vid)</option>
                    <option value="8">Ready for Ref Rev</option>
                    <option value="9">In Refraction</option>
                    <option value="10">Ready for Doc</option>
                    <option value="11">In Exam</option>
                    <option value="13">Retest Needed</option>
                    <option value="12">Ready for Signoff</option>
                    <option value="14">Complete</option>
                    <option value="15">Review Later</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <label class="mt-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" wire:model="is_contacts"> Is Contacts? </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="statusTimer60833" class="flaggedRow">
                    <div id="timer60833" style="display: inline-block" class="statusTimer"> <span data-minutes="" class="statusMinutes" data-row-id="60833">07</span>:<span data-seconds="">29</span> </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="examTimer60833" style="display: inline-block"> <span data-hours="">01</span>:<span data-minutes="">43</span>:<span data-seconds="">06</span> </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div onclick="focusStatusNotes(60833)" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; width: 183px; min-height: 30px; cursor: pointer; color: black">
                        <br>
                        <p>wants to try different cl</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr wire:id="YujsXyuGRw2YCGBU7fnl" data-status="3" data-selectable="itemRow" wire:ignore="" id="row60839" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffed4a , #e60000)" class="should-alert">
            <td scope="row"><a href="#" target="_blank">301591 </a></td>
            <td> <span wire:click="setCurrentLocation(337)" style="cursor: pointer" title="499">
                DS00138/CA
            </span>
                <br> </td>
            <td wire:click="buildDocReassignModal" style="cursor: pointer; "> Dr. Chin </td>
            <td id="usercell60839" class="userCell" data-id="">
                <button wire:click="take">Take</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select wire:model="status" class="block-refresh">
                    <option>Ready for Refraction</option>
                    <option value="1">Testing</option>
                    <option value="4">Ready for Ref (spanish)</option>
                    <option value="5">Ready for OR</option>
                    <option value="6">Ready for OR (Spanish)</option>
                    <option value="7">Ready for Ref (no doc vid)</option>
                    <option value="8">Ready for Ref Rev</option>
                    <option value="9">In Refraction</option>
                    <option value="10">Ready for Doc</option>
                    <option value="11">In Exam</option>
                    <option value="13">Retest Needed</option>
                    <option value="12">Ready for Signoff</option>
                    <option value="14">Complete</option>
                    <option value="15">Review Later</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
                    <div style="font-size: 16pt; color: rgb(155, 155, 155)" role="button" class="mr-3">
                        <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-robot fa-w-20" onclick="flagIt(60839)" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="robot" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
                            <path fill="currentColor" d="M32,224H64V416H32A31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1,0,384V256A31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1,32,224Zm512-48V448a64.06328,64.06328,0,0,1-64,64H160a64.06328,64.06328,0,0,1-64-64V176a79.974,79.974,0,0,1,80-80H288V32a32,32,0,0,1,64,0V96H464A79.974,79.974,0,0,1,544,176ZM264,256a40,40,0,1,0-40,40A39.997,39.997,0,0,0,264,256Zm-8,128H192v32h64Zm96,0H288v32h64ZM456,256a40,40,0,1,0-40,40A39.997,39.997,0,0,0,456,256Zm-8,128H384v32h64ZM640,256V384a31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1-32,32H576V224h32A31.96166,31.96166,0,0,1,640,256Z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <label class="mt-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" wire:model="is_contacts"> Is Contacts? </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="statusTimer60839" class="flaggedRow">
                    <div id="timer60839" style="display: inline-block" class="statusTimer"> <span data-minutes="" class="statusMinutes" data-row-id="60839">28</span>:<span data-seconds="">45</span> </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="examTimer60839" style="display: inline-block"> <span data-hours="">01</span>:<span data-minutes="">25</span>:<span data-seconds="">25</span> </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div onclick="focusStatusNotes(60839)" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; width: 183px; min-height: 30px; cursor: pointer; color: black">
                        <br> </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that final `.appendTo($tbody)` is interesting.

Comment: I copied it from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28190005/7315363

Comment: showing the referenced html will help analysis

Comment: I've added a screenshot containing the `data-status` attribute

Comment: "outputting xx logs"  doesn't make any sense.

Comment: please show us the related html; before and after sorting would help.

Comment: If the "first run" sorts properly then I expect subsequent sorts to not change that order.

Comment: I've added the html as a screenshot from the inspector. The actual code is quite massive and hard to follow because it's being generated from a framework. So I just referenced the compiled version with the relevant data. And when I say I'm outputting 46 logs, that's the number from my console screen above. You can see that the first run of the `sortItems()` functions logs "sorting" 46 times. Every run after that only logs it 15. So I'm assuming that something is happening between the first and second run

Comment: When I run it the first time, I will change the `data-status="3"` to something else like `data-status="19"` then run `sortItems()`. This works correctly. Then I'll do the same for a second row and it does not work. Only the first row was sorted correctly but nothing changes in the table after i run `sortItems()` one time no matter which other `data-status` attributes I change

Comment: I bet you have only 15 rows in that table, so you get `46` on first run because of number of permutations during sorting, then on subsequent runs you get `15` because the rows are already sorted.

Comment: so how would I make it run "fresh" every time after the initial run so that it runs through every permutation when i call the function again?

Comment: What do you mean by "fresh"? You must change the position of rows in the table after sorting to get different results if that is you mean.

Comment: I am. I will change the `data-status` value to something else and it will not sort according to the new value

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question as text, not as pictures of text. Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources

Comment: what about the information that I provided is insufficient for you to help? There are no error messages, I've provided the console output that I think is related to the issue. you want all 500 lines of framework code instead of a compiled screenshot that contains the data related to the question?

Comment: The javascript references missing html. Include the referenced html. If `queueTable` is 500 lines (rows), I assume all the data rows have the same structure, so just enough rows to understand what is being sorted. Plus all the table structure tags - `table`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, and so on.

Comment: i've included the html of the table with two rows.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes here in the future, here's how I eventually solved it. I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117860/sorting-js-array-without-reloading-page) answer and it kind of got me on the right track. Now, instead of appending to the table, I'm rebuilding the entire html of the table at the end of the function which is allowing the sort function to operate twice in a row without a page refresh.

```
const sortList = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 17, 9, 16, 10, 18, 11, 19, 13, 12, 14, 15]
function sortItems() {
    initRows = $('[data-selectable="itemRow"]')
    newRows = initRows.sort(function(a, b) {
        console.log('sorting')
        return sortList.indexOf($(a).data('status')) > sortList.indexOf($(b).data('status')) ? 1
                    :
                    sortList.indexOf($(a).data('status')) < sortList.indexOf($(b).data('status')) ? -1
                    :
                    0;
            });
            $("#queueTable tbody").html(newRows)
        }
```